# Iphone saving a slow video with open gl filter

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, video-capture, avcapturesession, glreadpixels

I am using avcapturesession with a preset AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium to capture video, i am applying effect on this video with opengl using shaders.
I use assetWriter to write the video to an mp4 file. The problem is that the resulted video is slow specially when I add audio output.

This is how my code works :

1. In -
   (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput
   *)captureOutput... function I apply the opengl filter to the captured
   frames
2. then check if the captureoutput is
   video or audio if it's video, I use
   glReadPixels to create a
   CVPixelBufferRef that I send to an
   AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
   to write it
3. if it's audio, I write directly the
   CMSampleBufferRef

If someone can tell me what's wrong with my approach or which part is supposed to make the resulted video slow?

Comment: You mean it's slow as in the program runs too slow and you're dropping frames or you're writing every frame but the final video is playing at e.g. 1/2 speed? If the former then have you run your program through Instruments?

Comment: The problem is when i capture audio with the video, i think i drop frames. Because when i capture only video and save it without the audio I get a good speed.